# Getting The Application Server installation directory is not correct in RAD 9.0.1

Tags: websphere, portlet, ibm-rad

While Adding Websphere Portal 8 Server in RAD 9.0.1 results in "The Application Server installation directory is not correct" error.Can you please let me know how to solve this issue.

Comment: Which directory are you specifying?

Comment: Its a application server installation directory, while adding portal server its asking both application and portal server installation directories path.But am able to add websphere portal server 8 localhost on WAS 85 in RAD 9.0.1.

Comment: Thanks for the information, but now am able to add WebSphere Portal v8.0 Server on WAS 85 in RAD but not able to add WebSphere portal server v8.0. I have installed RAD seperately and with combined WAS and portal server instalaltion. Installed Websphere Application Server 8.5.5.

Comment: I'm confused... You are writing that you are able to add WebSphere Portal v8 , but you are not able to add WebSphere Portal Server???

Comment: Yes i am not able to add the WebSphere Portal v8.0 Server at localhost in RAD but able to add the WebSphere Portal v8.0 Server at localhost on WAS 85.

Comment: Portal requires WAS. If it is installed with WAS 8.5, you will only be able to add Portal Server on WAS 85. If it is installed with WAS v8, then you use the other. You cannot use both for same installation.

Answer (score 1):

Check this link [Adding Portal 8 Server in RAD 9.0.1 results in "The Application Server installation directory is not correct" error](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21662923)

> ```
> Potential causes include:
> - You have not selected the WebSphere Portal Server 8.0 on WebSphere Application 
>    Server 8.5 adapter.
>    Note: You may have mistakenly selected the WebSphere Portal 8.0 Server adapter or
>    you may not even have the WebSphere Portal Server 8.0 on WebSphere Application 
>    Server 8.5 adapter available to choose from in RAD.
> - You are not providing the right installation directory for your Portal or WAS 
>   server. The WAS server you are pointing to which is to be used with Portal 8
>   is not compatible with Portal. 
> Note: You must be using a WAS ND server
> ```

Ensure you have the WebSphere Portal Server 8.0 on WebSphere Application Server 8.5 adapter and not the WebSphere Portal 8.0 adapter.

> If you do not see the correct adapter available:
>
> 1. Close RAD
> 2. Open IBM Installation Manager
> 3. Click Modify > Select the RAD 9.0.1 package group > Next > Next.
> 4. You should now be on the feature selection page.
>      Under the Server tools section, ensure to have the Development tools and the Remote server stub installed for the Portal version and
>      WAS version you are looking to install
>
>    For example: If you are looking to install Portal 8 with WAS 8.5.x, ensure you have the Development tools and the Remote server stub also installed for the WebSphere Portal Server 8.0 on WebSphere
>      Application Server 8.5 option
> 5. Click Next > Modify